# Internationalising with multiple views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action called `index` that returns a view and I've defined 3 views: `index.cshtml`, `index.fr.cshtml` and `index.sv.cshtml`, each of which contains my page in a different language.  I expected my app would automatically find these views and serve them according to the browser language preference set, but it doesn't seem to.

is there some switch I have to turn on to make this work? I did add `<globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" />` to the `<system.web>` section of my `web.config`

TIA - e

Answer (score 0):

If you go down this road, make a view per language you will end up with a lot a views and DUPLICATE code. something you want to avoid. A better approuch is the use of resources.

You can decide how far you go with globalisation : javascript / urls / tekst. The key is to make use of resources and put the key value pair there. Please look at http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/How-To-Achieve-World-Ready-Domination-In-ASP-NET-MVC-4

Comment: thanks.  most of the app uses resources for the task, however what I'm interested in localising at this point would much more easily be managed via multiple views.  I know it's possible to do it, I just don't know why I can't make it work

Answer (score 0):

The index.mode.cshtml is for browser display mode of the ViewEngine.

You have to create a custom ViewEngine for localization. [Here is one for WebForm](http://brianreiter.org/2011/03/23/simple-asp-net-mvc-globalization-with-graceful-fallback/). Just modify it to your needs and inherit from RazorViewEngine instead of WebFormViewEngine.

Comment: You can create custom display mode for languages but I don't recommend it since it current purpose is browser classification.